# ffmpeg rtsp to hls streaming choppy and stops automatically

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, rtsp

I use ffmpeg + nginx/rtmp to restream video from ip cam to web page.  The command I use is:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.28.120/ -f flv -c:v copy -c:a copy rtmp://hls.mydomain.com/show/120
```

Then I use this URL to watch it in chrome:

http://hls.mydomain.com:8080/hls/120.m3u8

The problem is that the video in chrome is very choppy and can barely last only a few minutes before it stops.

On the re-streming server, I saw that ffmpeg quit automatically, without any error output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.28.120/':
  Metadata:
    title           : SDP Descrption
    comment         : SDP Description
  Duration: N/A, start: 1604569309.322911, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://hls.mydomain.com/show/120':
  Metadata:
    title           : SDP Descrption
    comment         : SDP Description
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0x5559c1d26940] CSeq 6 expected, 0 received.0:16.73 bitrate=2725.1kbits/s speed= 1.1x    
[rtsp @ 0x5559c1d26940] CSeq 6 expected, 0 received.0:21.50 bitrate=2447.1kbits/s speed=1.08x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rtsp @ 0x5559c1d26940] CSeq 6 expected, 0 received.0:35.10 bitrate=2191.8kbits/s speed=1.05x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
[rtsp @ 0x5559c1d26940] CSeq 6 expected, 0 received.0:39.04 bitrate=2180.5kbits/s speed=1.04x    
    Last message repeated 2 times
[flv @ 0x5559c1d30440] Failed to update header with correct duration.406.8kbits/s speed=1.03x    
[flv @ 0x5559c1d30440] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame= 1009 fps= 17 q=-1.0 Lsize=   17912kB time=00:01:00.28 bitrate=2434.0kbits/s speed=1.02x    
video:17401kB audio:459kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.288416%
```

I confirmed that the exit code of ffmpeg is 0. Streaming and serving are on two standalone Debian Linux server.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, I would like to know the command like arguments to re-stream H265 video.  TIA.